# WCF invoke not interfaced method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

just came across a problem.
I'm trying to make a wcf service unittest ready or better all code have to be tested with unittest.

Atm its not possible coze I've got a connection to a crm 2011 server that is used every time.
so i replaced it with a Interface. but i want to unittest the WCF like you use it.
now my idea is to make a public method and and give a fake connection.

now my question is would it be possible to invoke this method(example: ConnectionHandler), even if its not in the interface?

this would look like this:

```
public interface IWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool method1();

    [OperationContract]
    bool method2();
}

public class WCF:  IWCF
{

    public bool method1(){
    ...
    }

    public bool method2(){
    ...
    }

    private connection connectionHandler;
    public connection ConnectionHandler(Iconnection con){
        if(con != null){
            connectionHandler = con;
        } else {
            connectionHandler = takedefault;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
ah i forgot to tell this: im actually have the security in mind, i don't want that anyone can pass a different connection to the server its for unittest purpose only.

Comment: have you tried to mock your connection ? You should have a look at different mocking frameworks, since this is exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yeah thats what im trying to do :-D but if i can t inject the mocked connection i cant unittest it. but with the answer form user2382536 i understand how to do this. my concern were, dont let the client have access to change the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of important features of any well designed piece of code is that you are explicit about the functionality that you expose to your clients.  This becomes a key feature of service orientated applications, as you are exposing your functionality in a standardised way for external clients to consume.

Calling a method that is not part of the interface is bad in principle as you are now programming to the implementation and not the interface. Happily WCF knows this and will not let you a method that is not on the interface as it is not decorated with the  `OperationContract` attribute.

With respect to your code - I am not sure exactly what it is you are trying to achieve - to have a client set (what I assume is) something like a database connection makes me a little uneasy (for a start this means your service is holding some state which goes against the [Service statelessness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_statelessness_principle)). This does not mean that what you are doing is necessarily wrong, but you should find that you only rarely have to violate this in a well designed application.

That said, if you want to expose different areas of functionality to different clients the correct way to do this is by exposing endpoints on your service representing the different contracts:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool method1();

    [OperationContract]
    bool method2();
}

 [ServiceContract]
public interface IConnectionWCF
 {
     [OperationContract]
     bool SetConnection(string connection);
 }

 public class WCF : IWCF, IConnectionWCF
{
     public bool method1()
     {
        ...
     }

     public bool method2()
     {
        ...
     }

     public bool SetConnection(string connection)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

You also need to be mindful that everything the WCF service received must first be serialized by the client, sent over the wire, and deserialized on the server.  You are very much dealing with concrete classes here - not abstractions.  Passing an interface (such as `Iconnection`) as an argument to a service call does not really make any sense in a service-orientated environment.

With regards to unit testing - just remember that fundamentally the class `WCF` is just a plain old class. You can unit test this class in isolation of the fact that it is a WCF service.  You shouldn't be setting up any of the service hosting functionality within your unit tests anyway - you want to check that the code that YOU write is correct - the WCF stack has already been tested by Microsoft.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19000188/2382536), you should used constructor injection to set the connection object when the class is instantiated.  This then raises the question of how you gain control over the instantiation of the WCF service.  You need to implement `IInstanceProvider`, or for a more detailed implementation see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx).  This way, when you service is hosted in WCF, you use `IInstanceProvider`, when you are testing you simply pass your fake connection object to the constructor.

**EDIT**

To clarify, a unit test for this class would resemble this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        Iconnection connection = new FakeConnection();
        WCF classUnderTest = new WCF(connection);

        //Run test logic
    }
}
```

Comment: first im trying to unit test my WCF methods(method1/method2). 
And as far they have direct connection to crm 2011/DB server.
Now i want to remove this direct connection so i can inject a fake connection so i can test these methodes.
but i dont what to give the wcf caller the ability to change the connection :-D

Comment: this way if someone is calling my wcf  its still possible to to give a diffrent connection with it right? i want only unit test be able to give a custom connection to my wcf

Comment: Just saw in the svc/wsdl file you will not be able to give a parameter for the constructor ?! is this right?

Comment: Using IInstanceProvider the control over what gets injected into the constructor is given to the hosting environment, which you are in control of (clients are not).  Another alternative would be to also provide a default parameterless constructor that sets the connection to a default value.  This constructor is used when the class is served up as a WCF service, the other constructor is used to set the connection in the testing environment.

Comment: You can provide a parameter to the service, it just requires a bit more work. See the link I posted above. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to invoke this method, you can cast the interface to the concrete object. But that would compromise the calling code, which should not know the implementation details of your service.

I would reccomend in your sittuation to use the constrcutor injection so your service implemetation would look like this:

```
 public interface IWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool method1();

    [OperationContract]
    bool method2();
}

public class WCF:  IWCF
{
    private connection connectionHandler;

    public WCF(Iconnection con)
    {
         if(con != null){
            connectionHandler = con;
        } else {
            connectionHandler = takedefault;
        }
    }

    public bool method1(){
    ...
    }

    public bool method2(){
    ...
    }



}
```

In this case the client code will not know the details of the service implementation, if you use the constrcutor injection on the client as well

Comment: ah i forgot to tell this: im actually have the security in mind, i don't want that anyone can pass a different connection to the server its for unittest purpose only.